# Wordpress - add first post title to category title, also on subpages

Tags: php, wordpress, title, categories

I wonder that apparently noone has asked this before and after searching, checking and "cowboy coding" for hours I´m nearly ready to give up... 

**The (WP-)Problem:** When you have a category with lots of posts and many category subpages, you normally have the category name in <title> and (on subpages) also a unique identifier appended (like "Page 2 of 99"). 
For SEO purposes and readability it would be nicer to add something more "descriptive". My Idea: Why not adding first post title to category <title> on every (sub-)page? Just like

<title> category 1 My funny first post</title>
<title> category 1 (subpage 1) My other first post on the second site</title>

**The Question:** How can I get the category title and every first post title from subpages to interconnect and to get unique results in the end?

Ideally this should happen in functions.php or custom plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple.You have just to find the template of category post and add the following code with category title:

```
<?php echo get_cat_name( $cat_id ) ?>
```

Here $cat_id is your category id which you want the name.

You have to get the parent category id and then get only one post of that category and set order by asc/desc post id (as you want latest or oldest).In this way You always find the parent category first post data and you pick whatever you want.In your case post title will be useful.

Comment: Hm, thanks...but: The main thing is not the cat_name, but always the "first post title" from every category subpage...

Comment: You have to get the parent category id and then get only one post of that category and set order by desc post id.In this way You always find the parent category first post data and you pick whatever you want.In your case post title will be useful.

Comment: Ah, yes....you´re right: The Idea is simple, but logical. I´ll try to put it together....

Comment: Ok, it´s done and working- no probs. That was a quite silly thing to ask..... :-)  Thank you!